# Unable to set alternate app icons in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9-beta

I am unable to change the app's icon to an alternate icon in iOS 11 (Xcode 9, beta 3).

However, it works fine in iOS 10.3 (with the following code):

```
    if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
        guard let iconName = MySingletonClass.sharedInstance.iconName() else { return }
        delay(0.01) {
            UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(iconName, completionHandler: { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Success!")
                }
            })
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

My plist is set-up like so:

[image]

I find it odd because I have used other apps that use alternate app icons in iOS 11. Is there a known bug with this in iOS 11?

Note: If you're wondering why I'm using the delay, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195325/setting-alternate-app-icon-returns-error-3072-the-operation-was-cancelled-in)

Comment: Did you check the `supportsAlternateIcons` upfront?

Comment: @BennX How so? I thought that's a read-only property that is true if the plist values (as pictured) are provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by implementing it in a ViewController, rather than the AppDelegate's appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Still need to run it within a delay for it to work though, as related questions / answers point out.

Answer (score 0):

If this will not help, disable app icons assets. It helps me.
I guess there is some conflict between assets and plist icons.